# Two Private keys on Weblogic

Tags: web-services, weblogic, private-key

How to access two private keys on Web logic server or via Java code.
Any pointers would help.
Below is the piece of code, but it throws key is tampered or password is wrong.

Similar code works if i pass the the truststore or keystore location as direct location like .trustStoreFile("C:\Test\XYZTrust.jks")

If i change the code like below it throws

```
/* Get the JKS contents */
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        try (final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fullPathOfKeyStore())) {
            keyStore.load(is, JKS_PASSWORD);
        }
        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, KEY_PASSWORD);
        final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        /*
         * Creates a socket factory for HttpsURLConnection using JKS
         * contents
         */
        final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());
        final SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

Error :- Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Note:- Password and keystore are 1000 % correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your Keystore using Admin-console.
Got to Environment -> Servers -> AdminServer.
You should see something like this:
[image]

In the field "Custom identity Keystore"is the path to your Keystore file,
and in the field "Custom Trust Keystore" is the path to your Trust key.

In case you don't have the correct Password you can use the following link to decrypt them.

http://techtapas.blogspot.de/2011/05/how-to-decrypt-weblogic-passwords-with.html?m=1

If you are using default passwords then most of the chances that this is one of those:
https://itguykelly.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/default-weblogic-keystore-passwordpassphrase/

Comment: But when we try it from the plain java class it still fails .

Comment: Detail:- I am trying to have multiple keystore from java client, but it fails with following msg
{"error":"Not logged in"}
Becoz Weblogic server  container does the SSL handshake before the java program calls and invalidates the request.

Comment: issue in short is
simple CXF client to communicate with a remote service protected by SSL weblogic, weblogic overides the certificate sent by client and uses the weblogic default keystore.